# SQL GroupBy and Where won't work at the same time

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

I'm new to SQL Server, I'm trying to create temp table with the group by and the where clause but end always with a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help?

obrigado.

```
 SELECT Receb, NomeReceb 
 INTO #RecebedorTemp
 FROM m.estvendas
 GROUP BY Receb, NomeReceb 
 WHERE NomeReceb IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: TYpically, `WHERE` needs to come **before** `GROUP BY`..... unless you're using an exotic SQL database - please add a relevant tag! (`mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or whatever else you might be using)

Answer (score 1):

the order of the clauses seems off;  group by comes AFTER where

```
 SELECT Receb, NomeReceb 
 INTO #RecebedorTemp
 FROM m.estvendas
 WHERE NomeReceb IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY Receb, NomeReceb
```

also, no need to group by when you are not using any aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to use `m.` before every attribute that belong to `estvendas` table

Here is what i wrote :

```
SELECT m.Receb, m.NomeReceb 
INTO #RecebedorTemp
FROM m.estvendas
GROUP BY m.Receb, m.NomeReceb 
WHERE NomeReceb IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: it works, but had to change order of group by and where just like Randy wrote.